# Nifi - nipyapi - Updating processor's sensitive variables

Tags: python, apache-nifi, nipyapi

I keep on getting the following error while running `nipyapi.canvas.update_variable_registry(versionedPG, variable)` API from nipyapi.

Do I need to refresh the flow before making this call. Is there any nipyapi call to do the same ?
I referred the following link https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/NIFI-processor-not-the-most-up-to-date/m-p/158171 which states that if you are modifying the component from 2 different places, then I could see this errors. But in my case, I am running python code to modify and update the processor & components.

Also, what does 5 in the error below means.

```
ERROR:main:[5, null, 0d389912-2f27-31da-d5d2-f399556fb35e] is not the most up-to-date revision. This component appears to have been modified
```

How to get the most up-to-date revision of the processor ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like `update_variable_registry` is not the good way to update those variables.

[image]

According to Nifi http logs examination, you have to

1. Create an update request through a POST. This is done using [`submit_update_variable_registry_request(...)`](https://nipyapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nipyapi-docs/nipyapi.nifi.apis.html#nipyapi.nifi.apis.process_groups_api.ProcessGroupsApi.submit_update_variable_registry_request)
2. Wait for completin using through a GET of this update request. This is done using [`get_update_request(...)`](https://nipyapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nipyapi-docs/nipyapi.nifi.apis.html#nipyapi.nifi.apis.versions_api.VersionsApi.get_update_request)
3. Finally DELETE the update request. This is done using [`delete_update_request(...)`](https://nipyapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nipyapi-docs/nipyapi.nifi.apis.html#nipyapi.nifi.apis.versions_api.VersionsApi.delete_update_request)

After having tried that, it seems like only the first part is really needed. Part 2 and 3 may be elements of UI refresh ...

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved in version 0.13.3 of NiPyAPI [Github](https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi)